# Comparing multinomial logistic coefficients across groups

Tags: interaction, group-differences, multinomial-logit

I have a multinomial logistic regression model - 1 DV with 3 categories and 5 IVs (4 continuous and 1 categorical). I would like to test whether my effects differ between different ethnic groups. 
Is it possible to do this without running the analysis for each group separately?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Is ethnicity your categorical IV? Could you tell us a little more about the data and other variables?

Comment: Thank you for you interest. My dependent variable is future aspirations and it has three outcomes: low, middle and high. I predict these outcomes by different variables. I would like to check whether the patterns I get are 'general' or specific to only some ethnic groups (I have 4 ethnic groups).